# Counterintuitive drop in CPU

Tags: linux, performance, central-processing-unit, memcached, cpu-usage

I am running a memcached service in a linux container pinned to a specific physical core. As expected the CPU increases when the number of requests increase. The requests are sent from a workload generator on another machine. However, for a given number of requests, the amount of CPU used varies in counter intuitive ways under different scenarios. The machine has 4 physical cores(0,1,2,3) and hyperthreading has been disabled.

1) Memcached runs alone on a single core (CPU0)

2) Memcached runs on a single core (CPU0), and a CPU intensive application(does many floating point operations) runs on (CPU3).

As an example, Memcached uses a CPU of 88% for 60000 requests per sec for scenario 1. For the same 60000 requests per sec, Memcached uses a lower amount of CPU of 78% for scenario 2. How is this possible? Why does CPU usage of Memcached drop when a CPU intensive application runs on a different core?

Some interrupt results for each core from mpstat:

scenario1(memcached running alone on CPU0):

```
CPU usage of Memcached = 88%

Average:     CPU       HI/s    TIMER/s   NET_TX/s   NET_RX/s    BLOCK/s BLOCK_IOPOLL/s  TASKLET/s    SCHED/s  HRTIMER/s      RCU/s
Average:       0       0,00     231,61       0,20  102893,92       0,00       0,00       0,00       4,14       0,18      42,53
Average:       1       1,80      18,33       0,00       0,00       0,00       0,00       0,98       4,25       0,02      15,98
Average:       2       0,00      22,96       0,00       0,00       0,00       0,00       0,00       3,47       0,02      20,49
Average:       3       0,00      20,59       0,00       0,00       0,78       0,00       0,00       3,43       0,02      18,71
```

---

Scenario 2: (memcached on CPU0 and CPU intensive application on CPU 3)

```
CPU usage of Memcached = 78%
Average:     CPU       HI/s    TIMER/s   NET_TX/s   NET_RX/s    BLOCK/s BLOCK_IOPOLL/s  TASKLET/s    SCHED/s  HRTIMER/s      RCU/s
Average:       0       0,00     204,87       0,21  102268,58       0,00       0,00       0,00       2,77       0,40     133,05
Average:       1       0,03      24,94       0,00       0,00       0,00       0,00       0,55       5,56       0,06      23,38
Average:       2       0,00      17,23       0,00       0,00       0,00       0,00       0,00       4,23       0,04      16,12
Average:       3       0,00     250,00       0,00       0,00       0,74       0,00       0,00       2,50       0,00      37,69
```

Comment: I'm not sure if CPU-pinning makes sense in a container.

Comment: I am not sure if I was clear. By CPU pinning I meant using the cgroups feature for CPU isolation of the whole container and not memcached service alone.